# two prepositions following each other

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english, british-english

This is a title of an article , does is make any sense in English grammar?

*The effects of the age on human trust **in and** acceptance of self driving cars.*

if you look at the sentence again, two words of "in" & "and" are followed each other. does it correct ?

Regards.

Comment: _And_ is not a preposition. The two prepositions that are used in parallel are (trust) _in_ and (acceptance) _of_. There is not problem with your sentence, nor does some coincidental occurrence of "two words end up next to one another" in itself ever make a sentence ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the words you've bolded aren't both prepositions, "and" is a conjunction". The title does make sense, but it takes me a while to understand.

I don't see it as being grammatically wrong, but very clumsy. The reason you've found yourself having to structure the title in such a way is that the noun "trust" is followed by preposition "in" and "acceptance" is followed by preposition "of". Take the following example:

> "He has both reverence and respect toward his elders."

Here the construction is simpler because "reverence" and "respect" can be followed by the same preposition "toward". However it's not always the case and you may find yourself saying things like:

> "The voters were in favour of and clamouring for a change in
>   government."

This is fine grammatically, and may be necessary. But as a matter of style it can be seen as bad. It seems as if you're squeezing in prepositions just to make the sentence grammatical. In fact rewriting the entire thing from scratch, or splitting it into multiple sentences may be a better option.

Seeing as your example is an article title, splitting into multiple sentences is probably out of the question, but maybe something like this would work:

> "How age affects the way people trust and accept self-driving
>   cars."

What I've done here is made "trust" and "accept" into verbs instead of nouns, eliminating the need for a preposition, and so can be followed directly by "self-driving cars" as a direct object.